# Django: Change Choice selection from FK in a Form linked to an UpdateView

Tags: django, django-forms

The Model flow Topic -> Section -> Article.

I am building an Update View for my FAQ project to update already created Articles. I want the Form to provide a selection of Sections based on the Topic the Article was created under. As I already have the Articles PK passed in through the URL I was hoping to use it to walk back up to the Topic when creating my filter. I am receiving an `object has no attribute ‘section’` error when the template is attempting to render the form on line `self.fields['section'].queryset = Section.objects.filter(topic_id=self.section.topic.id)` in the UpdateAriticleForm. I need help to figure out my query filter.

**The URL:**

```
url(r'^ironfaq/article/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ArticleUpdateView.as_view()),
```

**The Form:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Topic, Section, Article

class CreateArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    section = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Section.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        topic_pk = kwargs.pop('topic_pk')
        super(CreateArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['section'].queryset = Section.objects.filter(topic_id=topic_pk)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        widgets = {
            'answer': forms.Textarea(attrs={'data-provide': 'markdown', 'data-iconlibrary': 'fa'}),
        }
        fields = ('title','section','answer')

class UpdateArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    section = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Section.objects.none())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UpdateArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['section'].queryset = Section.objects.filter(topic_id=self.section.topic.id)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        widgets = {
            'answer': forms.Textarea(attrs={'data-provide': 'markdown', 'data-iconlibrary': 'fa'}),
        }
        fields = ('title','section','answer')
```

**The View:**

```
class ArticleUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = UpdateArticleForm
    template_name = "faq/form_create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        article = form.save(commit=False)
        article.activity_user = self.request.user.username
        article.activity_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        article.save()
        self.success_url = "/ironfaq/%s/%s/%d" % (article.section.topic.slug,article.section.slug,article.id)
        return super(ArticleUpdateView,self).form_valid(form)
```

**The Models:**

```
class Topic(Audit):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
    sort = models.SmallIntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "topics"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Section(Audit):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sort = models.SmallIntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "sections"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(Audit):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sort = models.SmallIntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.TextField()
    vote_up = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    vote_down = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "articles"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the this issue was not passing `'pk'` as a argument to the form and to add get_form_kwargs to the view to enable the form to see the `'pk'` passed in the URL.

Form:

```
class UpdateArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    section = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Article.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['section'].queryset = Section.objects.filter(topic_id__exact=Article.objects.filter(id=pk).first().section.topic.id)
```

View:

```
class ArticleUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = UpdateArticleForm
    template_name = "faq/form_create.html"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ArticleUpdateView,self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(self.kwargs)
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        article = form.save(commit=False)
        article.activity_user = self.request.user.username
        article.activity_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        article.save()
        self.success_url = "/ironfaq/%s/%s/%d" % (article.section.topic.slug,article.section.slug,article.id)
        return super(ArticleUpdateView,self).form_valid(form)
```